# "To <verb>+ing" vs. "To <bare verb>"

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund, to-infinitive

On a website I have read:

> #### Interpreting the assignment question
>
> There are usually three steps **to analysing** an assignment question.
>   Some questions may involve more than one task.
>
> <sub>Source: http://owll.massey.ac.nz/academic-writing/interpreting-the-assignment-question.php</sub>

Why does the writer not use "to analyse"? What difference does it make? Is there any rule for when to use the `-ing` form instead of the bare verb form after *to*?

Comment: I don't have a complete answer, but I think it's not really the presence of *to* that makes the difference - instead, you should think of "to *verb*" as one indivisible phrase, the infinitive of the verb.  The question is then "when do you use the infinitive and when do you use a gerund"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*To* here is the ordinary preposition. *Steps* is a metaphor which expresses a process as a staircase composed of individual steps, and we often use *to* to express the components of a whole:

> Twelve pieces *to* the puzzle ...
>   Three keys *to* the upcoming match ...
>   Two parts *to* the assignment ...

The preposition *to* calls for a 'nominal' (noun-like) object to express this whole, and the *-ing* form of a verb is the one which can act syntactically as a noun (in this case traditional grammar calls the *-ing* form a "gerund"), so that is the form selected. The author might also have used a frank noun:

> There are usually three steps to *analysis* of an assignment question.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to use the word **to**: As a preposition and as infinitive.

When it's used as a preposition, it takes -ING, which is the case of many verbs that can only be proceeded by to as a preposition:

I'm addicted to **doing it**

He is allergic to **helping my friends**

They are used to **playing in evenings**

These examples mentioned above have **to** acting as a preposition, not as an infinitive.

These are one of the verbs that can only be proceeded by **to** as a preposition. How to identify when to use **to** as a preposition? I'm afraid there is no way to identify it, all you can do is memorize all verbs that are proceeded by **to** as preposition, and some of them I have already mentioned above.

One typical expression followed by **to** as preposition:

> *I'm looking forward to seeing you*.
>
> *I'm looking forward to hearing from you*.
>
> *We are looking forward to meeting you*.

Here is one list of verbs that will always take **to** as a preposition: [Verbs followed by gerund](http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/gerund2c.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what would you get in your mind if I say: I'm looking forward to see you ? or There are usually three steps to analysis an assignment question ?

Comment: @Gamal Thomas: Some verbs (***hope, want, love***, etc.) can be followed by an infinitive - for example, *I **promise to behave***. But others (such as ***look forward to***) don't work like this, and [as the British Council points out:](http://learnenglishteens.britishcouncil.org/grammar-vocabulary/grammar-videos/verb-ing-or-verb-infinitive) ***Sorry, there isn’t a rule. You have to learn which verbs go with which pattern.***

Answer (score 2):

"Analysing an assignment question" is a [gerund phrase](http://chompchomp.com/terms/gerundphrase.htm) that acts like a noun.  It's different from the present progressive (-ing) form of the verb.  You should become familiar with it because it is very frequently used.  For example:

> I enjoy skiing, sailing, and riding horses.

Your example sentence is of the form "There are three steps to (something)", where "something" is a noun or noun phrase of some kind.  Usually this requires a gerund since it's hard to have "steps" without an action.

> There are three steps to baking a perfect cake.
>
> There are three steps to writing a good essay.
>
> There are three steps to learning to appreciate opera.

And so on.